# Angular2 ngFor: when add/remove DOM? how to force it recreate DOM?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am playing with Angular2 *ngFor and have a little confusing about when it recreate DOM.

If I only have case 1 code inside `onClick()`, then it will recreate two `<li>`, but I just assign the same value to this.objArr.

If I only have case 2 code inside `onClick()`, then it doesn't recreate two `<li>`, and just add one more `<li>`. I wonder how ngFor determine when to recreate DOM.

**What I want to do is**:

If I just push more object into the existing array, how can I let it recreate the existing DOM for me besides add DOM for the pushed object? Like in case 2, I hope ngFor can recreate the first two `<li>` for me.

Html:

```ts
 <button (click)="onClick($event)"></button>
    <li *ngFor="let obj of objArr"></div>
```

.ts file:

```ts
    constructor() {
         this.objArr = [
                    {
                        'id': 0,
                        'content': 'test0'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': 1,
                        'content': 'test1'
                    }
                ];
    }

   onClick() {
       // case 1: recreate two <li>
       this.objArr = [
                    {
                        'id': 0,
                        'content': 'test0'
                    },
                    {
                        'id': 1,
                        'content': 'test1'
                    }
                ];

        // case 2: just add one <li> after the two existing <li>
        this.objArr.push({
             'id': '2',
             'content': 'test2'
        });


   }
```

Comment: you can use pipe for that

Comment: @VinayPandya Can you explain more detail based on my example?

Answer (score 4):

You can temporarily set `objArr` to null and "force" Angular to update the DOM by calling `detectChanges` in between:

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

onClick() {
  var tmp = this.objArr;
  this.objArr = null;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  this.objArr = tmp;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the difference between `this.objArr = null;` and `this.objArr = [ ];`? Will `this.objArr = [ ];` just keep the original reference?

Comment: Changing the value of `objArr` and running change detection forces `*ngFor` to remove all items, and adding them back makes `*ngFor` re-add them.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Couldn't you use the OnPush strategy, and then `cdRef.markForChange()`?

Comment: I guess so, but `OnPush` wasn't mentioned in the question.